# Safari opens pages but web view is not

Tags: ios

I am using `UIWebView` to load a page, the page to load is made with ajax asynchronous, I don't know why, my `UIWebView` is not able to load the page, but Safari is able to load the same.

Any help related to the same is appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code of what you had tried so far so that we can find out the problem.

Comment: can you include code?

Comment: I have solved my problem, I changed the UIWebView WKWebView, it is good, I also don't know why this is, loaded a synchronous request USES ajax web pages, I think this is strange.